# Issue with REST API service testing, JSON format response showing up in XML tab, but not converted to XML

Tags: json, xml, soap

So as a part of a new job I am being trained on SOAP ui, and I am having a bit of an issue. I am connecting to an existing service and getting an order from said service and then testing some assertions on it.

I have reached a problem though. The response coming from the service is in JSON format, but my SOAP UI seems to believe it is in XML format. So it puts the entire message, uncoverted from JSON, into the XML tab and the JSON tab says this response can't be viewed in JSON.

So to be clear when I look at my XML tab I see something like this (this is all fake data so no private health information is being leaked)

```
<data contentType="text/plain; charset=utf-8" contentLength="8690">< [CDATA[{
  "OrderResponse": {
    "OrderId": 3918208,
    "Source": "",
    "AccountNumber": "JJ357",
    "ReferringPhysician": "",
```

and so on. So my SOAP UI can't read it and I can't seem to be able to make my program figure out that this is the JSON and it needs to be converted to XML.

I know the problem is on my side. This is working code that they have tested and works with their current testing suites. So I have done something break my SOAP, and I honestly have no idea what. I have mentioned this to them, but would like to be able to have a solution by the time they get back to me, so as not to seem like I'm going to need to have my hand held every step.

If anyone can help that would be great.

Edit:  So upon further investigation it looks like the problem is that it is a JSON message in an XML envelope making it unreadable as either to SOAPUI. Using groovy script the message can't be parsed by JSONslurper or XMLparser, so if anyone happens to have dealt with this before that would be amazing.

Comment: Look at RAW and check the content-type headers in request and response...

Comment: Looks like there isn't a content-type in the request, but in the response the conten-type is text/plain; charset=utf-8